# Reading selection with its span tags with Rangy

Tags: rangy

I'm setting a font size for a selection using the CssClassApplier in Rangy:

```
.font16 {font-size: 16px;}
.font17 {font-size: 17px;}
.font18 {font-size: 18px;}


var font16Applier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("font16");

function applyfont16() {
            font16Applier.applyToSelection();
        }
```

Now if someone presses a "+" to bump the font size I'd like to be able to read the class name in the span tag for the selection and if it's, say, font16, change it to font17.

But I'm not seeing any way in Rangy to read a selection with it's span tags.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code I'm seeing in your question does not correspond to what I'd expect to see in an attempt at implementing the 'if someone presses a "+"...' functionality. Including the code you've tried and providing a link to a jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com example would go a long way towards clarifying what you are working with structure-wise and exactly does not work. Or, to put it differently, it helps us help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement a jsfiddle with the entire Rangy library.  The missing "+" code is just: read the current selection including its span tags and apply the next font size up the same way font16 was applied above. It's the "read the current selection including its span tags" that I don't know how to do with Rangy, or any other way.

Comment: There is a box on the left to add resources in jsFiddle which you could use to include files from http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/currentrelease/ or http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dev/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a class applier for each font size, you could just iterate through each in turn and check if it is already applied to the current selection. It's not very efficient but may perform well enough.

```
var font16Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font16");
var font17Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font17");
var font18Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font18");

var appliers = [font16Applier, font17Applier, font18Applier];

for (var i = 0, len = appliers.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (appliers[i].isAppliedToSelection()) {
        if (i < len - 1) {
            appliers[i].undoToSelection();
            appliers[i + 1].applyToSelection();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! A similar problem is displaying the font family of a selection. I guess I'll just have to run through an array of all the fonts and display the one that hits.