# Rangy iterate thru getSelection classes

Tags: javascript, css, rangy

im using Rangy Library from Tim to make a "Simple" text editor, i use static class for Italic, Bold, Strike and Underline like:

myCss.css

```
.n {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.i {
font-style: italic;
}

.t {
text-decoration: line-through;
}

.s {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

if i want to toggle a specific class i just sent the value so it will be used in the createClassApplier and apply it to the selection like this:

```
applier = rangy.createClassApplier("n");
applier.toggleSelection();
```

it work flawless. Now im trying to implement foreground and background color, i thought about creating a dynamic style class called foreground and set the text-decoration-color for the one that the user selected(From color picker) OR use a pre-build classes like

```
.color1 { 
text-decortion-color: red;
}

.color2 { 
text-decortion-color: blue;
}
```

and go on..

but in this way i need to get the selected text CLASSES and than iterate and check if its already set, if not, remove other setted colors and than add the new one (hard way?)

i`d prefer to use something like:

```
applier = rangy.createClassApplier("f");
applier.text-decoration-color: #000FFF;
```

but ofc it will not work outside my mind lol..

if iterating is the "hard way", what would be a good/best way to apply colour for background and foreground?

Answer (score 0):

one good approach was found and provided by the creator of Rangy ->

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22528320/2582318

create new applier for each class of color and than iterate thru it to check is its applied

```
var font16Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font16");
var font17Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font17");
var font18Applier = range.createCssClassApplier("font18");

var appliers = [font16Applier, font17Applier, font18Applier];

for (var i = 0, len = appliers.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (appliers[i].isAppliedToSelection()) {
        if (i < len - 1) {
            appliers[i].undoToSelection();
            appliers[i + 1].applyToSelection();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```